# how to include yaffle event source polyfill

Tags: polyfills, eventsource

https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource

I used the above because I want to get promises to work in IE11, I have installed it with npm but not sure how I'm suppose to implement it. I tried `import event-source-polyfill` in my js file but that hasn't worked either. The doc says just to run build, but what is the purpose of that if I already see the min.js file int he node_modules/event-source-polyfill directory? How do actually include it?

Answer (score 1):

To get at your root problem, you probably want something like https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise if you want a polyfill for Promises.

For Yaffle/EventSource, that's a polyfill for [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource). You can make sure that works by adding the path to the javascript to your client-side front-end (i.e., your HTML webpage) like so:

`<script src="./node_modules/event-source-polyfill/src/eventsource.min.js"></script>`

You don't need to build it unless you want to make sure the generated javascript (eventsource.min.js) is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource right now, I import it like this:

```
import { EventSourcePolyfill } from 'event-source-polyfill';
```